# MSBuild Silently Skipping One Project (out of many in my sln)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

About to lose my mind with this one... A solution build when run via MSBuild is silently failing to build one of many projects in the solution.

The build doesn't fail, it simply never attempts to build it at all (ascertained via the log files MSBuild and devenv output).  This is a VS2010 solution file. Let's call the problem project Project X.  What I know:

- I have a solution which contains ~30 projects.
- All of these projects are set to build under Release|Win32.  I have double and triple (and quadruple) checked this.
- If I build the solution in VS every project builds correctly, including Project X.
- If use *the same exact command that MSBuild is using to launch devenv*, Project X builds.
- If I launch MSBuild passing it my project file, Project X is not built, not noted as skipped, just... not there at all (in the logs and output dir).

I have poured over the project file time and time again.  All it really does is launch devenv like so:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Devenv.com" "MySolution.sln" /build "Release|Win32"

Again, if I use that *exact same command* in a prompt Project X is built.  I have enabled diagnostic level logging in MSBuild to no avail.  I'm at a loss at this point, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i've no idea, but is Project X the last project to be built when it works? (i'm thinking some limit somewhere in default running of MSBuild ~2^5 maybe)

Comment: @mcalex: Nope, but a good thought. I actually *just* fixed it, after a day of troubleshooting and 5 minutes after posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a shot in the dark - but I've had this issue before and have found that unloading the offending project and reloading it back into the solution does the trick. I have never determined why it happens, nor had anyone else explain it to me, but doing this has solved the issue two or three times for me on different solutions.

Comment: And that did the trick.  I tried it right after posting this question, was about to post this answer myself.  I don't understand it. I diffed the previous sln and vcxproj files from before and after re-adding it... they are semantically identical.  However, problem solved... yeesh.

Comment: Ha - glad you got it working! It's just one of those mysteries.

Comment: Yeah, I just wish it made sense... now I have to come up with an automated way to make sure that everything in this project is *actually* building or I'll never trust it again (this was found as a result of a bug reported from the field).

Answer (score 1):

I've removed `ProjectSection(ProjectDependencies) = postProject` from the `Project` which caused the problem in the sln file. This helped.

Comment: This helped me as well but the issue is then you'll have a build race without this dependency.